# Wordpress - Include data from new column in the search query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I added a new column to Woocommerce orders's screen, that indicates who is the order's creator (in that site, service representatives have the ability to create order for customer's in the backend).The problem is that when I search for that data in the orders screen, I can't find any.
The order's creator is set to the order with a`dd_post_meta()`
So I tried something like this:

```
function include_search( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_search() && $query->query['post_type'] == 'shop_order' ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array('key' => 'representative', 'value' => $query->query['s'], 'compare' => '=') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_search' );
```

But it doesn't work.

For example, If an order created by "Ben X", then I can see his name appears in the right column in the orders screen, but if I search for "Ben X" in the search box, I don't find that order.

Any help with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need help with that, I found the answer:

```
function filter_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields( $array ) {
    $array[] = 'representative'; //The order meta key that needs to be include in the search
    return $array;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 10, 1 );
```